# Zoho CRM - nodejs integration: Get more than 20 leads-contacts-potentials with a module

Tags: node.js, get, crm, zoho

I hope this subject hasn't been treated yet but I haven't found. 
I'm setting up a node integration with Zoho CRM and I want to get all the records from Leads or Contacts or Potentials.

I tried to use 2 node modules: zoho and node-zoho. Here are the codes:

zoho:

```
var Zoho = require('zoho');
var crm = new Zoho.CRM({
  authtoken: '[authtoken]'
});

crm.getRecords('leads', function (err, data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(data.data.Leads.row.length);
});
```

node-zoho:

```
var Zoho = require('node-zoho'),
    zoho = new Zoho({authToken:'[authtoken]'});

zoho.execute('crm', 'Potentials', 'getRecords', null, function (err, result) {
  if (err !== null) {
    console.log(err);
  } else if (result.isError()) {
    console.log('the result error is: ' + result.message);
  } else {
    console.log(result.data.length);
  }
});
```

Each time I get a result '20' for length even though I have more than 20 leads (or contacts or potentials). I'd like to get all the records.

Does someone know how to configure these modules better or know another trick to get all the records?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you generate that auth-token? From that self client?

Answer (score 0):

Default value for result is 20.
You have to pass {"fromIndex":1, "toIndex":200 } as a parameter.

take a look on this:
https://apigee.com/i.vatsenko/embed/console/zoho-crm